# how to provision a datastore in ckan for connecting cygnus in column persistance mode?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

I am having the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026522/fiware-cygnus-no-data-have-been-persisted-in-ckan) and try to solve it, but I do not know how to properly format the datastore so cygnus will not throw the persistence error.

My orion suscription is this one:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Event",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "es-leon-0"
        },
        {
            "type": "Event",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "es-leon-1"
        }

    ],
    "attributes": [
        "IdEvent", "IdUser", "Title"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [ ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT5S"
}
EOF
```

My cygnus config:

```
ygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = ckan-sink
cygnusagent.channels = ckan-channel

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = Papel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = Test
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 5
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.gropuing_rules_conf_file = /Applications/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/grouping_rules.conf

cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

# ============================================
# OrionCKANSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel

# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink

# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = false

# true if lower case is wanted to forced in all the element names, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.enable_lowercase = false

# the CKAN API key to use
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = xxxxx

# the FQDN/IP address for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = ckan-demo.ckan.io

# the port for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 80

# Orion URL used to compose the resource URL with the convenience operation URL to query it
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://localhost:1026

# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = column

# enable SSL for secure Http transportation; 'true' or 'false'
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false

# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100

# timeout for batch accumulation
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 60

# number of retries upon persistence error
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10
```

Cygnus is receiving right it but then shows the following error:

```
time=2016-04-21T07:44:57.504CDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1461242686-614-0000000001 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=getEvents | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[231] : Starting transaction (1461242686-614-0000000001)
time=2016-04-21T07:44:57.528CDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1461242686-614-0000000001 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=getEvents | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[258] : Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "571897360e94f9fa53829885",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "type" : "Event",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "es-leon-0",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "IdEvent",            "type" : "text",            "value" : "1084"          },          {            "name" : "IdUser",            "type" : "text",            "value" : "18"          },          {            "name" : "Title",            "type" : "text",            "value" : "Papes"          }        ]      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
time=2016-04-21T07:44:57.528CDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1461242686-614-0000000001 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=getEvents | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler[280] : Event put in the channel, id=2024732986 
time=2016-04-21T07:45:50.771CDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1461242686-614-0000000001 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=persistAggregation | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink[417] : [ckan-sink] Persisting data at OrionCKANSink (orgName=papel, pkgName=papel_test, resName=es-leon-0_event, data={"recvTime": "2016-04-21T12:44:57.497Z","fiwareServicePath": "Test","entityId": "es-leon-0","entityType": "Event","Title": "Papes"},{"recvTime": "2016-04-21T12:44:57.528Z","fiwareServicePath": "Test","entityId": "es-leon-0","entityType": "Event","IdEvent": "1084","IdUser": "18","Title": "Papes"})
time=2016-04-21T07:45:51.875CDT | lvl=ERROR | trans=1461242686-614-0000000001 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=processNewBatches | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[426] : Runtime error (Cannot persist the data (orgName=papel, pkgName=papel_test, resName=es-leon-0_event))
```

As said in [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/flume_extensions_catalogue/orion_ckan_sink.md#section2.3.1), I created the corresponding datastore: http://ckan-demo.ckan.io/dataset/papel-test/resource/8d7cb489-878e-465e-8c8c-60ea537411e0
But don't know how to format it or if the csv is the correct format.

Thanks

*Note: I tried in row mode and all works, but it's not what I want.

**Note: I also found an error in the previewer software changing the title of my column "Title" to the title of the page "CKAN Demo".

**EDITED:**

I have done what is said in the documentation:

**Column:** A single row is upserted for all the notified context attributes. This kind of row will contain two fields per each entity's attribute (one for the value, called `<attrName>`, and other for the metadata, called `<attrName>_md`), plus four additional fields:

- **recvTime**: UTC timestamp in human-redable format (ISO 8601).
- **fiwareServicePath**: The notified one or the default one.
- **entityId**: Notified entity identifier.
- **entityType**: Notified entity type.

But still have the same error:

```
time=2016-04-25T05:17:48.790CDT | lvl=ERROR | trans=1461579403-571-0000000000 | srv=Papel | subsrv=Test | function=processNewBatches | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[426] : Runtime error (Cannot persist the data (orgName=papel, pkgName=papel_test, resName=es-leon-0_event))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need a CKAN organization and package/dataset before creating a resource and an associated datastore in order to persist the data.

Creating an organization, let's say in [`demo.ckan.org`](http://demo.ckan.org/); the organization name is `frb`, because our entity will be in that FIWARE service:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/organization_create" -d '{"name":"frb"}' -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxx"
```

Creating a package/dataset within the above organization; the package name is `frb_test`, because our entity will be in the FIWARE service `frb` and in the FIWARE service path `test`:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_create" -d '{"name":"frb_test","owner_org":"frb"}' -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxx"
```

Creating a resource within the above package/dataset (the package ID is given in the response to the above package creation request); the name of the resource is `room1_room` because the entity ID will be `room1` and its type `room`:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/resource_create" -d '{"name":"room1_room","url":"none","format":"","package_id":"d35fca28-732f-4096-8376-944563f175ba"}' -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxx"
```

Finally, and answering to your question, creating a datastore associated to the above resource and suitable for receiving Cgynus data in column mode (the resource ID is given in the response to the above resource creation request):

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_create" -d '{"fields":[{"id":"recvTime","type":"text"}, {"id":"fiwareServicePath","type":"text"}, {"id":"entityId","type":"text"}, {"id":"entityType","type":"text"}, {"id":"temperature","type":"float"}, {"id":"temperature_md","type":"json"}],"resource_id":"48c120df-5bcd-48c7-81fa-8ecf4e4ef9d7","force":"true"}' -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxx"
```

Now, Cygnus is able to persist data for an entity with ID `room1` of type `room` in the `frb` service, `test` service path:

```
time=2016-04-26T15:54:45.753CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=getEvents | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[240] : Starting internal transaction (b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9)
time=2016-04-26T15:54:45.754CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=getEvents | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[256] : Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "temperature",            "type" : "centigrade",            "value" : "26.5"          }        ],        "type" : "room",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "room1"      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
time=2016-04-26T15:55:07.843CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=processNewBatches | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[342] : Batch accumulation time reached, the batch will be processed as it is
time=2016-04-26T15:55:07.844CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=processNewBatches | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[396] : Batch completed, persisting it
time=2016-04-26T15:55:07.846CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=persistAggregation | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink[419] : [ckan-sink] Persisting data at OrionCKANSink (orgName=frb, pkgName=frb_test, resName=room1_room, data={"recvTime": "2016-04-26T13:54:45.756Z","fiwareServicePath": "/test","entityId": "room1","entityType": "room","temperature": "26.5"})
time=2016-04-26T15:55:08.948CEST | lvl=INFO | corr=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | trans=b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9 | svc=frb | subsvc=/test | function=processNewBatches | comp=cygnusagent | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[400] : Finishing internal transaction (b465ffb8-710f-4cd3-9573-dc3799f774f9)
```

The insertion can be checked through the CKAN API as well:

```
$ curl -X POST "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_search" -d '{"resource_id":"48c120df-5bcd-48c7-81fa-8ecf4e4ef9d7"}' -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxx"
```